# put a list into a String[]

Tags: java

I have the below code:

```
 contacts = new Contact[] { 
      new Contact(0, "Mercury")
  };  
}
```

What I want to do is add values from a list of contacts, rather than Strings like Mercury!

How would I go about this?

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want?

Comment: You know about toArray, right?

Comment: Is Contact your own class? Probably should just tag this as java, not android. Are you trying to make a deep copy of an array?

Comment: @ DaveNewton Yes but I can't seem to implement it
@ StealthRabbi Contact is my own class.

@Enrichman, I am trying to use the values from a list of contacts to add them to a String[], which then gets passed to a custom adapter to be populated into a ListView

Comment: @faz15 If you're trying to make a String[] why are you making a Contact[]?

Comment: Same concept so I thought it'd be easier to explain:) thanks for your help guys, don't know why it was down voted:|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using the `List.toArray` method. Assumming you have a `List<Contact> lstContacts` or similar:

```
Contact[] arrContacts = lstContacts.toArray(new Contact[0]);
```

Comment: There's no need to cast if you pass an array as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html)'s toArray method, and cast it appropriately:

```
Contact[] contacts = contactsList.toArray(new Contact[0]);
```

Taking another look at that, you will need to hand it a Contact[] (empty of course), for it to know what class type to be using. However, you do NOT need to cast.

Comment: You can avoid casting by passing an argument: `contactsList.toArray(new Contact[0]);`

Comment: @AlexColeman: Yes, with edited answer, it is not required. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List<Contact> contactsList` with some data.

```
int size = contactsList.size();

Contact[] contacts  = new Contact[size];

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
   // selection logic here--

   contacts[i] = contactsList.get(i);
}
```

Now you have a Array `Contact[]`.

Comment: This is a very naive solution.

Comment: But it's 4x as long as it needs to be.